# How to fix VS2017 Error C1189 in stlsoft.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I tried to compile the source that demonstrate text to speech i got from this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17897/audio-ostream-A-Text-to-Speech-ostream)

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "audiostream.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace audiostream;

int main()
{
   try
   {
      audio_ostream aout;
      aout << "Hello World!"  << endl;
      aout << "<voice required='Gender=Male;Age!=Child'>Hello World!" << endl;

      aout << "Five hundred milliseconds of silence " << flush << "<silence msec='500'/> just occurred." << endl;


      for (int i=0; i<1e5; ++i)
      {
         cout << i << ' ';
      }

   }
   catch(std::exception &x)
   {
      cerr << "Unhandled error: " << x.what() << endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   catch(...)
   {
      cerr << "Unhandled unknown error" << endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Using Visual C++ 2017
I added the included directory of STLSoft-1.10.1-beta16 and it all dependencies bus fixed.

However, I'm getting this error below:

> Severity  Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C1189   #error:  Currently only versions 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.1, 8.0,
>   9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0, and 14.1x of the Visual C++ compiler are supported by the STLSoft libraries  Console c:\users...\speech
>   library\stlsoft-1.10.1-beta16\stlsoft-1.10-1.10.1-beta16\include\stlsoft  c:\users...\speech library\stlsoft-1.10.1-beta16\stlsoft-1.10-1.10.1-beta16\include\stlsoft\stlsoft.h  735

When i checked inside the header stlsoft.h i saw this code which launched the error.

```
/* ***************************** Visual C++ **************************** */
# define STLSOFT_COMPILER_IS_MSVC
# define STLSOFT_COMPILER_LABEL_STRING          "Visual C++"
# if defined(STLSOFT_FORCE_MSVC_4_2) && (_MSC_VER == 1020)
#  define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING       "Visual C++ 4.2"
# elif (_MSC_VER == 1100)
#  define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING       "Visual C++ 5.0"
# elif (_MSC_VER == 1200)
#  define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING       "Visual C++ 6.0"
# elif (_MSC_VER == 1300)
#  define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING       "Visual C++ 7.0"
# elif (_MSC_VER == 1310)
#  define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING       "Visual C++ 7.1"
# elif (_MSC_VER == 1400)
#  define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING       "Visual C++ 8.0"
# elif (_MSC_VER == 1500)
#  define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING       "Visual C++ 9.0"
# elif (_MSC_VER == 1600)
#  define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING       "Visual C++ 10.0"
# elif (_MSC_VER == 1700)
#  define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING       "Visual C++ 11.0"
# elif (_MSC_VER == 1800)
#  define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING       "Visual C++ 12.0"
# elif (_MSC_VER == 1900)
#  define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING       "Visual C++ 14.0"
# elif ((_MSC_VER & 0xFFF0) == 0x1910)
#  define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING       "Visual C++ 14.1x"
# else /* ? _MSC_VER */
#  error Currently only versions 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.1, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0, and 14.1x of the Visual C++ compiler are supported by the STLSoft libraries
# endif /* _MSC_VER */
```

I also changed the Language settings to support 14.x but still getting the same error.
[image]

I think the error is about the project very old and i used incompatible new version of stlsoft library. I'm not sure but i'm stack on how to fix this error. Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not the same thing: it meant Visual Studio version 14.0, which is 2015 I think, not C++ version. Probably the easiest thing to do is to add extra cases for your compiler, or change the #error to a #define STLSOFT_COMPILER_VERSION_STRING, and then work through and fix any further errors you come across. However if it's using these to select a `#pragma comment(lib, "...")` later then you might be out of luck, as you won't have a .lib built with VS2017.

Comment: I think you have to either complain to the people writing the software or edit the header to allow your _MSC_VER to be accepted. Figure out what your `_MSC_VER` is on your platform. its probably a little greater than `0x1910`' If you look at this chart there are different _MSC_VERs for Visual Studio 2017: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B)

Comment: This is painful to debug since there's no text to speech that work so far in my search. The errors are either some libraries are not anymore supported or not maintained. If you guys happen to find one that is working until now, please let me know about it. Thanks.